# how to build dependencies in snapshot with -fPIC using Haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to make stack 1.2.0, Ubuntu 16.04 system package, build dependencies from a snapshot with `-fPIC`.

I tried adding the following in the `<user>/.stack/config.yaml` file.

```
ghc-options:
  "*": -fPIC

rebuild-ghc-options: true

apply-ghc-options: everything
```

But it seems that it only affects local targets and dependencies specified in `extra-deps`. The dependencies in the snapshot are still not built with `-fPIC`.

I also tried `stack build --ghc-options='-fPIC'` from the command line, in addition to the modifications to the `config.yaml` file and it didn't work either.

What is the correct way to enabling stack to build dependencies from a snapshot with `-fPIC`?

Comment: you may want to read https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/10/static-compilation-with-stack

Comment: another tip: stack clean before you change your ghc-options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried `stack clean` but it still only recompile local targets and dependencies specified in `extra-deps`.